# Exporting internal library dependency to outer scope with browserify

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, browserify, bluebird

I'm using browserify for requiring bluebird for cross-browser compliant usage of promises in my [WebApi Wrapper for Dynamics CRM](https://github.com/DigitalFlow/Xrm-WebApi-Client).
It works great so far, however I don't like that I can't do `Promise.all` for example on my returned call results in IE, without including bluebird again in my top page.
For this reason I'd like my browserify bundle to expose Promise to the global scope. Of course it would work to just do `global.Promise = require("bluebird")`, but that feels kind of dirty.
Using a standalone bundle I made it, that my standalone exposes my client as property and Promise, too. However names get longer this way and I would like to just be able to use Promise (without my standalone wrapper) everywhere.

What do you think about that? Is that possible or should I not do that?

What I do right now is define my client as IIFE, and inside it do the following:

`module.exports = {
        Client: WebApiClient,
        Promise: Promise
    };`

and browserifying like `browserify src/js/WebApiClient.js -d --standalone XrmWebApi -o Publish/WebApiClient.js`.
This way I'm currently able to use XrmWebApi.Client and XrmWebApi.Promise, but I would very much like to get rid of the XrmWebApi for calling the promises.

Thanks for your help.

Kind Regards,
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new file for your global definitions and then add that as an entry point in your bundle step.

`src/js/globals.js`:

```
var bluebirdPromise = require("bluebird");
global.Promise = global.Promise || bluebirdPromise;
```

`browserify src/js/globals.js src/js/WebApiClient.js -d -o Publish/WebApiClient.js`

You will probably want to remove references to `bluebird` in your file `src/js/WebApiClient.js` and its dependencies and just use `Promise`.

Comment: Do you know whether it is a better practice to leave my client definition as IIFE, or would it be better to expose it as module.exports?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve so I will guess. The browser is not going to understand your `module.exports`. I had a look at your last commits on the project and I am guessing you are wondering about the IIFE with respect to the `globals.js` that you have added. It seems unnecessary. You should see the output that browserify gives you just from `browserify src/js/globals.js`. It will show in your terminal and you will see that the code is already wrapped for you in an IIFE.

Comment: I would comment the line which requires bluebird because it's only going to make the output unreadable. You'll see the `browserify` surrounding code is minified. An unsquashed version is over at https://github.com/substack/browser-pack/blob/01d3989/prelude.js if you want to study it with a little more ease...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, in fact I was trying to find the clearest way of exposing my modules. I guess it's ok as it is right now, since the IIFE in WebApiClient.js attaches my module to window or reuses an existing one. I checked the latest release, the bluebird require in WebApiClient does not seem to make it more unreadable? I wanted to add it so I can be sure that promise is always bluebird, even if the user has overwritten promise with something different.

Comment: By unreadable I just meant the output from `browserify` bundling your code would be noisy if you did a require in there so it would not be clear what `browserify` itself was adding in there. I tried to illustrate it better with this gist: https://gist.github.com/casr/6cb5de4aaf0a1f632e482cbbdab3e12f

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, I understand what you meant.